# ansible: it is possible to defining vars in a role

Tags: ansible

Can I define a var directly in a role ?

With the following I get an error with this role `ansible/roles/myrole/tasks/main.yml`

```
vars:
  source: /var/www/test.xxx.com/proj/assets
  dest:   /var/www/test.xxx.com/

- name: eb copy files
  shell: rsync -a  {{ source }} {{ dest }}
```

either with this:

```
  source=var/www/test.xxx.com/proj/assets
  dest=var/www/test.xxx.com/
```

I get a

```
ERROR: Syntax Error while loading YAML script
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To define variables inside of a task, you can use the [set_fact module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/set_fact_module.html).

```
- set_fact:
    source: /var/www/test.xxx.com/proj/assets
    dest: /var/www/test.xxx.com/
```

You can also set facts in a role, by placing variables in the vars directory.

```
ansible/roles/myrole/vars/main.yml
```